# Toggle Button State

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I would like to use a toggle button in my toolbar but I can't find out how to retrieve the state.
Could someone explain me how to do that?

```
<%= Html.Kendo().ToolBar()
    .Name("ToolBar")
    .Items(buttonsItem =>
    {
        buttonsItem.Add().Type(CommandType.Button).Text("Unconfirmed").Id("isConfirmed").Togglable(true).Toggle("isConfirmed");
    })

%>


function isConfirmed(e) {

    if (document.getElementById("isConfirmed").checked == true)
    {
        alert("yes")
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no")
    }
```

Regards

Comment: you're clearly making a mistake on the id you're trying to retrieve. And in c# I would retrieve the state via the IsChecked property.

Comment: Sorry, fast copy/Paste error! Fixed question! By the way it doesn't work with the correct Id! That's why I'm try to find out how to do it!

Comment: @ArDevTeam and relation with jQuery?

Comment: What do you mean @ebilgin?

Comment: @ArDevTeam you added a jQuery tag on your question but your question doesn't have a relation with jQuery.

Comment: It was suggested because you can use jquery too @ebilgin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the toggle event itself you can look at `e.checked` to determine the toggle state.

In this example I am also changing the text of the button depending on the checked state:

```
function isConfirmed(e) {
    var text = e.checked ? "Confirmed" : "Unconfirmed";
    e.target.text(text);
    alert(text);
}
```

If you want to get the state later (e.g. when a submit button is clicked), you can check the selected option of the button object (`$("#isConfirmed").data("button").options.selected`):

```
$("#btnIsConf").on("click", function(){
    if ($("#isConfirmed").data("button").options.selected){
        alert("Yes");
    } else {
        alert("No")
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/azoPE)**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to look the dom element back up to determine the state i.e. the `checked` property.

It is available in your `e` parameter as follows:

```
function isConfirmed(e) {

    if (e.checked) {
        alert("yes")
    }
    else {
        alert("no")
    }
}
```

**Screen Grab**

[image: Screen Grab]